# Heroku app crashes on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Today, I created a copy of a working app, which runs perfectly on Heroku, and tried to deploy it on Heroku as a starting point for a new project.

I added the new folder as a git repository, created a new remote repository on GitHub, edited the config file and gave new names to the databases, created the new databases and tried to deploy on Heroku.

When I try this the app crashes and from the remote logs I can see this:

```
2011-06-27T12:45:28+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 29758 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-06-27T12:45:32+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/routes.rb:42:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `id' for main:Object (NameError)
2011-06-27T12:45:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.6/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:227:in `draw'
2011-06-27T12:45:32+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you show your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: prolly you have some syntax msitake in your routes.rb file

Comment: It was indeed an error in my routes file!   The strange thing is that my other app works perfectly as it is.   Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the new app was running on a Ruby 1.9.2 stack while the older one was running on a 1.8.7 Ruby stack.  Transitioned to the old stack and now everything works fine!